# social login with google in django 400 error

Tags: gmail-api

socail login with google in django getting Error 400: invalid_request

website name:boan.in

Authorization Error
Error 400: invalid_request
device_id and device_name are required for private IP: http://172.31.8.75:8080/accounts/google/login/callback/
Learn more

Pleasae help me to resolve

Answer (score 0):

Google does not accept a local (private) IP address when doing Oauth or API calls. Instead, you can add an entry in your Windows hosts file for the local IP: `\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

```
172.31.8.75 fakedomain.com
```

Then change your call back URI from `http://172.31.8.75:8080/accounts/google/login/callback/`
to `http://fakedomain.com:8080/accounts/google/login/callback/`

Finally browse the service with `http://fakedomain.com:8080`

I had the same problem and it is resolved now.